Some tough and innovative problem books on data structures and algorithms
I have been reading the CLRS DSA book and want to go to the next level to get a really good brain at problem solving in the domain. Can anyone refer to such books or problem solving websites where we can learn such things . Thank you.

What's the "CLRT DSA" book for those who don't know? Do you mean CLRS? The question here is a bit broad. Is there are particular domain you're interested in exploring? Otherwise, there are probably hundreds of difficult algorithm books you could dive into.

I want the spectrum to be as broad as it is present today in the cs curriculum , also up to higher studies ,so that I can choose from them . Thank you @ggorlen.

What do you mean by "reading"? Are you also doing many of the exercises? Are you getting feedback on solutions? Simply reading this or another text won't advance you much.

No no I am doing excercises certainly from Kruth, and clrs.

Also trying some problems form websites like hacker rank and codechefs.

You say you "have been reading" and you want to get to some "next level". May I submit that you are not at any level if you only read? How about you take that book, and you try to derive all proofs yourself? Read problem descriptions and see if you can come up with algorithms / implementations that are as good as those in the book?
TLDR: you don't learn by reading, only by doing.
